# Decode a message using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, decode, encode

I am trying to decode a message which is encoded in Java. Below is the snippet of code from our Java developer:

```
$encrypted = base64_decode(urldecode($value));
  $decrypted = "";
  openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $key);
```

I am trying decode the string using Python with private key:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import base64
from urllib.parse import unquote

private_key="Private_key"
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
mesg='some mesg'
# For URL encoder
a=unquote(mesg)
encrypted=base64.b64decode(a.encode("utf-8"))
# before decrypt convert the hex string to byte_array 
message = cipher.decrypt(bytearray.fromhex(encrypted))
print(message)
```

I am getting an error below, and I am using Python 3

```
TypeError: fromhex() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: I dunno but did you just paste your private key on stackoverflow?

Comment: What makes you think that's Java?

Comment: Please make sure to invalidate that private key and replace it by a new one.

Comment: Invalidating the private key is important. I flagged the post but it is still visible if you view edit history.

Comment: Sure Poke will do.. It was a mistake

Comment: How to decode the data.

Answer (score 0):

Using pyCrypto on Python 2.7, This is how you can decrypt RSA Public Key encryption. In python 3 it may be slightly different, but I'm pretty sure it should be close or the same.

```
 from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
 from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA  

 key = RSA.importKey('PrivateKeyString', passphrase=None)

 def decrypt(self, message):
    return PKCS1_OAEP.new(key).decrypt(message)

 print(decrypt('EncryptedMessage'))
```

For more information on this, you should read the [Documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/).

For nerdier people than me, here's a little more on the Class/Object used for [this example](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP.PKCS1OAEP_Cipher-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following three *commented* scripts could enlighten how to apply [Asymmetric Cryptography with Python](https://medium.com/@ashiqgiga07/asymmetric-cryptography-with-python-5eed86772731) article to your problem (work in Windows 10, Python 3.5):

- `45360327_keys.py`    *subsidiary*, run only once, no output to std out:

  - creates a private/public key pair and saves them to `pem` files for further use in other scripts;
- `45360327_encrypt.py` *subsidiary*, creates an encrypted value:

  - takes a message to be encrypted from pipeline or from line argument. Uses a sample string (Czech pangram) if not supplied,
  - encrypts it using read public key, and
  - prints encrypted message converted to format required for safe transport (url-escaped base64 string);
- `45360327.py`         **primary answering**, *mimics the given (PHP) code snippet*:

  - takes a value to be decrypted from pipeline or from line argument (mandatory), and prints decrypted string (decrypts using previously saved private key).

**Sample usage** (default string)

```
.\SO\45360327_keys.py
.\SO\45360327_encrypt.py|.\SO\45360327.py
```

> ```
> Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy
> ```

**Sample usage** (supplied a Russian pangram to encrypt/decrypt, `pem` files already created. **Important!** in Windows: `chcp 65001`:

```
>NUL chcp 65001
echo Друг мой эльф! Яшке б свёз птиц южных чащ!|.\SO\45360327_encrypt.py|.\SO\45360327.py
```

> ```
> Друг мой эльф! Яшке б свёз птиц южных чащ!
> ```

**45360327.py** (this script contains my answer):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

# the script mimics the following (PHP) code snippet: 
'''
  $encrypted = base64_decode(urldecode($value));
  $decrypted = "";
  openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $key);
'''

# take value from pipeline or from the first line argument
import sys
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    for arg in sys.stdin:
        value = arg.replace('\n', '').replace('\r','')
else:
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        value = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        value=''

from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import base64
from urllib.parse import unquote

encrypted_message = base64.b64decode( unquote( value))

# import private key from file, converting it into the RsaKey object   
pr_key = RSA.import_key(open('privat_45360327.pem', 'r').read())

# instantiate PKCS1_OAEP object with the private key for decryption
decrypt = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key=pr_key)
# decrypt the message with the PKCS1_OAEP object
decrypted_message = decrypt.decrypt(encrypted_message)

print(decrypted_message.decode('utf8'))
```

**45360327_encrypt.py** (subsidiary script):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
# take the message to be encrypted from pipeline or from line argument
import sys
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    for arg in sys.stdin:
        rawmessage = arg.replace('\n', '').replace('\r','')
else:
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        rawmessage = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        rawmessage='Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy'
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from binascii import hexlify
import base64
from urllib.parse import quote, unquote
# import public key from file, converting it into the RsaKey object   
pu_key = RSA.import_key(open('public_45360327.pem', 'r').read())
# instantiate PKCS1_OAEP object with the public key for encryption
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key=pu_key)
# prepare the message for encrypting 
message=unquote(rawmessage).encode("utf-8") 
# encrypt the message with the PKCS1_OAEP object
encrypted_message = cipher.encrypt(message)
# send the encrypted message to std output (print function does that)
print(quote(base64.b64encode(encrypted_message)))
```

**45360327_keys.py** (subsidiary script, **run once**):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# generate private key (RsaKey object) of key length of 1024 bits
private_key = RSA.generate(1024)
# generate public key (RsaKey object) from the private key
public_key = private_key.publickey()

# convert the RsaKey objects to strings 
private_pem = private_key.export_key().decode()
public_pem = public_key.export_key().decode()

# write down the private and public keys to 'pem' files
with open('privat_45360327.pem', 'w') as pr:
    pr.write(private_pem)
with open('public_45360327.pem', 'w') as pu:
    pu.write(public_pem)
```

Comment: I'm trying to decode a big string, always get ValueError("Ciphertext with incorrect length."), php code works with $chunkSize = ceil(1024 / 8);   $chunk = substr($encryptString, 0, $chunkSize); how to do the same in python 3? encodedString[:math.ceil(1024/8)] doesn't work